# appears to be have malfunctioned?

Tags: word-usage, word-order

I recently found this sentence below.

> Staff email on Outlook ***appears to be have malfunctioned***.

Now I'm just confused. Is it the abbreviation of ***"appears to be to have malfunctioned"*** or anything? How could be a verb(be) followed by another verb(have)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be confused, as the sentence is not grammatical.  The "be" is extraneous, and is likely a typo.  It should be:

> Staff email on Outlook appears **to have** malfunctioned.

It's possible someone first wrote something like:

> Staff email on Outlook appears **to be** malfunctioning.

then changed their mind.